# How to omit CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR from codebuild output artifact?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a CodePipeline which has a few stages, both Plan and Check are CodeBuild projects:
Source (Github) > Plan > Check

The files from the github source are used in plan and then at the end of the plan I use output artifact to export all the files in CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR using this:

```
  files:
    - '$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/**/*'
  name: PlanArtifact
```

In the export s3 bucket the files are outputted in the same pathways so CODEBUILD_SIR_DIR/all-files
I want to export the artifact so the s3 bucket is just immediatelly all-files, i want to omit the CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR as it changes with each codebuild and I just need the files in the .zip to use. I tried playing around with the below code but it doesn't seem to work:
`base-directory: '$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR'`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR variable from the files it should work:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  name: PlanArtifact
```

CodeBuild will always look for the artifacts in the original build location (ie. $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR), so there is no need to include it into the path.

base-directory can be used if you only want one or more subdirectories as artifact. If you set it, CodeBuild will go to that directory first (starting from the original build location, so it should be a relative path, too) and then start to resolve the files pattern.

[artifacts/files in the buildspec reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.files)
[artifacts/base-directory in the buildspec reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.base-directory)